# Applying & calling 2 filters in JTable filter

Tags: java, regex, swing, filter, jtable

I am coding a program which applies 2 filters to the `JTable` and then give me the results.

```
public void rowF(String one, String two){
    RowFilter<DefaultTableModel, Object> rf = null;
    List<RowFilter<Object,Object>> filters = new ArrayList<RowFilter<Object,Object>>(2);
     filters.add(RowFilter.regexFilter(one, 0));
     filters.add(RowFilter.regexFilter(two, 1));
     rf = RowFilter.andFilter(filters);
   }
```

This as I understand is the method to do so. But the problem is when I am calling it, it's not showing the result.

This is the code of the button - Search.

```
String quer = jtxtsearch.getText();
String query = jtxtsearch2.getText();

String search = (String)jcbox.getSelectedItem();
String perch = (String)jcbox2.getSelectedItem();

if (search.equals("ID")){
   if (perch.equals("Date")){
         rowF(quer,query);
     }
}
```

Comment: You have to compare string with equals.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I compare strings in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java)

Comment: For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/). In that example code, address (as in **fix**) the string comparison problem identified by @Rcordoval.

Comment: Tip: Add @Rcordoval (or whoever, the `@` is important) to *notify* the person of a new comment. *"the string comparison is working"* There are times when using the wrong methodology does work, but more important are the times it *doesn't work* (likely to be the next random VM the code is run on). So instead of explaining that it 'works', just **FIX it.**

Comment: Fixed it @Rcordoval and thank u

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the one that worked for me:

```
public void builtxsize (String one,String two){
  TableRowSorter<TableModel> sorter = new TableRowSorter<TableModel>(jtablestate.getModel());
  jtablestate.setRowSorter(sorter);
  RowFilter<TableModel, Object> firstFiler = null;
  RowFilter<TableModel, Object> secondFilter = null;
  List<RowFilter<TableModel,Object>> filters = new 
  ArrayList<RowFilter<TableModel,Object>>();
  RowFilter<TableModel, Object> compoundRowFilter = null;
    try {
      firstFiler = RowFilter.regexFilter(one, indexofcolumn);
      secondFilter = RowFilter.regexFilter(two, indexofcolumn);
      filters.add(firstFiler);
      filters.add(secondFilter);
      compoundRowFilter = RowFilter.andFilter(filters); 
      } catch (java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException e) {
          return;
      }
  sorter.setRowFilter(compoundRowFilter);
}
```

Calling it can be done as:

```
String one = jtxt.getText();
String two = jtxt2.getText();
builtxsize(one,two);
```